# Badge Cart Updated with many request on Click with $_SESSION

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

I have a litle problem with many requests from my badge.

I using the folow code from below, but i need update one time badge just only for one click.

How add timeout after one refresh?

This is my code:

```
<span class="label label-default" id="badge">
<?php count($_SESSION["cart"]); ?>
</span>
```

and script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#badge").load("badge.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#badge").load('badge.php');
   }, 1000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
```

and code for badge.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
echo count($_SESSION["cart"])
?>
```

Request Image:

[image]

I waiting best way for solve this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Well you used 10 for the interval. This will send 100 requests per second.

Comment: are you aware that setInterval takes MILLIseconds? you're posting 100 times per second...

Comment: If you want a better interval, remember that  1000 miliseconds = 1 second.

Comment: I used for add to cart and i need to update by click. I use fast interval for live update, but with not click from form button, have continuous request. I need only for a click, if have anybody an ideea.. Thank you!

Comment: Yes @Phiter, i set but problem with request is slow but this exiting too. I use this for update list of cart. Maybe need to try other way... Thank you!

Comment: Yes @LarsStegelitz .

Comment: This is the best way to kill you servers quickly, once a few couple of people are executing this code... basically a self-inflicted DoS attack :)

Comment: @LarsStegelitz it's true and this it's reason for added this question. I looking for other way for update my badge. Thank you!

Comment: @LarsStegelitz, i will check requests from facebook and i see same by me, but with other interval :) For SEO maybe it's very good and my server it's ok. Badge request have a small size and not problem, but i hope found another way with control of request by button only.